# Peculiar StandardSetController Issue with Test Class

Tags: unit-test, standardsetcontroller

Currently I have a test method that is proving to be quite difficult to test.

I currently have a controller extentsion that is used for a custom list view button.

The test code gets almost every line except for one. Despite all my effort, I still cannot get the final line.

Here is the test code (*editted of course*):

**Test Code**

```
static testMethod void SimpleTest() 
{
    List TestExamples = (TestsObjectGeneratorUtility.RetrieveGenerator(Example.sObjectType)).GenerateTestsObjects(5, true);

    Test.startTest();

    ApexPages.StandardSetController StandardsObjectController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId FROM Example]);//TestExamples);
    OwnerExtensionController MyExampleControllerExtension  = new OwnerExtensionController(StandardsObjectController);

    MyExampleControllerExtension.NewOwnerPlaceholder.OwnerId = System.UserInfo.getUserId();
    MyExampleControllerExtension.TransferOwnership();

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

The generator code does produce my Example records, which I could easily find with some debug code:

> 13:15:20.754 (14754824000)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|INFO|Examples used: (Example:{Name=Test Example 0, ExampleFieldName=Trying, RecordTypeId=..., Id=...}, ...

**Note: I commented out the passing of the List that was generated directly to the SetController because it threw the following: *System.VisualforceException: Record set cannot be empty.*

 
However, the records not only exist but if you query for them, the controller works and proves the records were created.**

The controller code itself is rather simple:

**Controller Code**

```
public with sharing class ExampleOwnerExtensionController 
{
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController StandardsObjectController;
    private List SelectedExamples { get; private set; }

    public Example NewOwnerPlaceholder { get; set; }
    public Boolean HasExamplesToTransfer { get { return this.SelectedExamples.Size() != 0; } }

    public ExampleOwnerExtensionController (ApexPages.StandardSetController SetStandardsObjectController ) 
    {
        this.NewOwnerPlaceholder = new Example();
        this.StandardsObjectController  = SetStandardsObjectController;
        this.SelectedExamples = (List)this.StandardsObjectController.getSelected();
    }

    public PageReference TransferOwnership()
    {
        ExampleOwnershipTransferUtility.TransferOwnershipOfExamples(NewOwnerPlaceholder.OwnerId, this.SelectedExamples);

        return StandardsObjectController.cancel();
    }
}
```

This code is all covered but, the tranfer utility runs into a snag in its coverage.

**Utility Code**

```
public without sharing class ExampleOwnershipTransferUtility 
{
    public static void TransferOwnershipOfExamples(Id NewownerId, List SelectedExamples)
    {
        for(Example SingleExample : SelectedExamples)
            SingleExample.OwnerId = NewownerId;

        UPDATE SelectedExamples;
    }
}
```

The line `SingleExample.OwnerId = NewownerId;` never gets covered.

So the big question is, what exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, SelectedExamples is empty. You need to set the selected records in your test prior to instantiating your extension:

```
 StandardsObjectController.setSelected(listOfObjects);
```

Comment: That was it! I had a feeling as soon as I posted it, that was a place to start. All-in-all, thank you so much for such a swift answer!